# Altair change the orientation of column labels

Tags: python, plot, altair

This plot has dates across the top of the columns. They flow over each other making them difficult to read. Is there a way to rotate these vertically? I could not find the solution online.

```
rr_st = alt.Chart(dfag).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('rebalance_range:O', title=""),
    y=alt.Y('mean(annual_return):Q', title='annual return'),
    column= alt.Column('start_date', title=""), 
    color=alt.Color('rebalance_range:O', title='rebalance range')
)

rr_st
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

These are the labels for the column header; as such you can use `Header(labelAngle)` within the `column` encoding:

```
alt.Chart(dfag).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('rebalance_range:O', title=""),
    y=alt.Y('mean(annual_return):Q', title='annual return'),
    column= alt.Column('start_date',
        title="",
        header=alt.Header(labelAngle=90)
    ), 
    color=alt.Color('rebalance_range:O', title='rebalance range')
)
```

Comment: Perfect. I actually had the labelAngel part but wasn't sure how to implement it. BTW, I'm just learning Altair and love it. Keep up the great work!